# In Excel, 'ALT and =' is returning a symbol instead of the sum function

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

In Excel 2010, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> is returning a symbol instead of the sum function. How do I get sum function back?

Comment: In the formula tab of excel, in the function insert area, is autosum the selected one? Hover and see if the alt = shortcut is displayed. Also have you restarted the computer? Any macros running?

Answer (score 0):

The "=" symbol is what you use to indicate the start of a function.  Say you want to autosum cells a1 through a5, and put the result in a6:

In cell a6, type =sum(a1:a5) and press Enter.  You don't need to press Atl-= to start defining the function.  You can also type =sum(), click in the middle of the parentheses, and then click and drag from the first cell to the last cell.

You can also click the fx key to start defining the function.